# Update Parent Property When Child Property Changes in Angular2 ( Child component loaded using router-outlet)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am very new to Angular 2.
We are developing a menu based angular app using router-outlet.

I have a field in App.component.html, let say  - JobName , which is binded using a property in app.component.ts and ng-model attribute.

User can go to a menu (say, SelectNewJob ) and can select a new Job.
SelectNewJob is another component loaded using  router-outlet tags

When User change job in SelectNewJob tab, I need to Update JobName field in app.component.html.

How can I do this.? I have tried Event Emitters, but it not working with router-outlet. Is there any other way to achieve this (using service..etc)

Please help.

Comment: Use a service or try to use ngrx to keep a global state

Answer (score 0):

One of simple ways to solve this problem is service. You can place some Subject there and subcribe to it in components. Service body will look like so:

```
private jobName: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

public get _jobName(): Observable<string> {
  return this.jobName.asObservable();
}

public updateJobName(name: string): void {
  this.jobName.next(name);
}
```

don't forget about imports

and in your components you cant do something like this

```
public jobName: string = '';

constructor(private jobService: JobService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.jobService._jobName.subscribe((name: string) => {
    this.jobName = name;
 }
}

public updateName(newName: string): void { 
  this.jobService.updateJobName(newName);
}
```

where JobService is the name of you service

this approach will solve your problem , but don't forget to cleanup subscriptions in ngOnDestroy()

Comment: throwing error @ return this.jobName.asObservable();, saying jobName.asObservable() is not a function.